# I'm having trouble finding a regular expression to find "$i=0" and not "$i==0"

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having trouble finding a regular expression to find `$i=0` and not `$i==0` in the following input: `$i=0; if ($i==0) Console.Write($i)`.

I've tried including something like `[^==]?={1}?` in my expression, but it still matches both cases.

This is on Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Can you be more detailed about what you want to match? At present you don't need a regular expression, or you can use a regular expression with no meta-characters, as you say you want to match an exact string.

Comment: Please add a more detailed question. This answers your question but pretty sure it's not what you're looking for `\$i={1}0`

Comment: Please check the solutions below, is any of them working for you? If not, please explain precisely what you are doing. I see you need to match a single `=`, but your regex will match `=` even inside a string literal like the second `=` in `$i="this=that"`. Do you need to consider these cases? If yes, you should consider using the appropriate lexer / grammar, one single regex will be inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^==]` won't negate expression `==`, because it matches everyhing except what is in the brackets, meaning you just excluded `=` twice, making it equivalent to `[^=]`.

What you want is to assert that what preceeds `=` is not another `=`, meaning you need negative lookbehind: `(?<!=)`.

So the pattern would be `\$.(?<!=)=([^=])`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IIjJgP/2)

Comment: Michael, that negative lookbehind worked!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this should find an assignment of an integer to a variable as opposed to the comparison:

```
string match = @"$i=0";
string noMatch = @"$i==0";
string pattern = @"\$\w+={1}\d+";
Console.WriteLine("Match" + Regex.Match(match, pattern).Success);
Console.WriteLine("No Match" + Regex.Match(noMatch, pattern).Success);
```

Explanation

`\w+` : match 1 or more occurences of letters
`={1}` : match only 1 occurence of the operator
`\d+` : match 1 or more occurences of digits

Output:

> Match: True
>   No Match: False

Here is your test input:

```
string testInput = @"$i=0; if ($i==0) Console.Write($i)";       
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(testInput, pattern).Value);
```

Output:

> $i=0

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe you might want to design an expression that'd look like:

```
\$[^=]+=\s*\d+
```

not sure though.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jMuuDL/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/jMuuDL/1debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.